# "Allow Payments on Mac" missing from my iPad

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, apple-pay, wallet

I'm trying to set up my Macbook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) to use Apple Pay.  All of the tutorials online say you need to go into your iPhone or Apple Watch under **Settings > Wallet & Apple Pay** and enable the "Allow Payments on Mac" setting.  I have an iPad with Touch ID running iOS 12.0.1 (latest version to date), but I do not see this option under **Settings > Wallet & Apple Pay**.  Also, I have my Mac and iPad successfully paired together with Bluetooth.

Is it possible to set up Apple Pay on my Mac with my iPad?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you logged in with the same Apple ID on both your iPad and MacBook?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in with the same Apple ID on both devices.

Comment: Possibly relevant... I am using a Sandbox Apple ID as I have been trying to test an Apple Pay implementation on a website.  I found someone who reported a similar issue but no resolution noted: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76681  --  Upon second glance they linked to a stack overflow post which was resolved with the answer that you cannot do this on an iPad (only iPhone and Apple Watch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it is not possible to use Apple Pay on a non-touch ID Macbook with an iPad.  Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611472/how-do-you-test-apple-pay-in-safari) linked below as well as Apple who specifies ["iPhone or Apple Watch"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208531) and does not specify iPad at all in relation to older Macbooks being compatible with Apple Pay.